# How to equate data in Polars？

Tags: python-polars

```
import polars as pl

data = {'test': [77, 36, 55, 0, 100, 32, 66, 72, 42, 1, 33, 100, 55, 69, 87, 45, 45, 66, 37, 89, 32, 38, 78, 85, 23, 43, 10, 14, 55, 32, 27, 88, 90]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

Suppose there is a set of data, which is the exam scores of students. After sorting them in descending order, divide the scores into ten equal groups according to the total number of students, with the same number of students in each group (rounded up). Then, based on the group in which the exam score falls, label each score as A+, A, A-, B+, B, B-, C+, C, C-, or D.

polars version = 0.17.9

Comment: This is a trickier question that it seems on the surface. For example in your test data, you've got 33 values that you want to divide into 10 groups. Well, 33/10=3.3 so you need 3 groups of 4 and 7 groups of 3. What if on the boundary you've got 2 people with the same score but the groups can't be balanced unless they're in different groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this "works"

```
(df
.with_columns(grade=(pl.col('test').rank('ordinal')/(pl.count()/10)).ceil().cast(pl.Int8())
    .map_dict({10:'A+',9:'A',8:'A-',7:'B+',6:'B',5:'B-',4:'C+',3:'C',2:'C-',1:'D'})))

shape: (33, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ test ┆ grade │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 77   ┆ A-    │
│ 36   ┆ C+    │
│ 55   ┆ B     │
│ 0    ┆ D     │
│ …    ┆ …     │
│ 32   ┆ C     │
│ 27   ┆ C-    │
│ 88   ┆ A     │
│ 90   ┆ A+    │
└──────┴───────┘
```

I say "works" in quotes because it arbitrarily determines edge cases.

For instance if we check the min/max grade of each group...

```
(df
    .with_columns(grade=(pl.col('test').rank('ordinal')/(pl.count()/10)).ceil().cast(pl.Int8())
    .map_dict({10:'A+',9:'A',8:'A-',7:'B+',6:'B',5:'B-',4:'C+',3:'C',2:'C-',1:'D'}))
    .groupby('grade')
    .agg(pl.col('test').min().alias('min'),
         pl.col('test').max().alias('max'),
         pl.count().alias('n'))
    .sort('max'))


┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ grade ┆ min ┆ max ┆ n   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ D     ┆ 0   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   │
│ C-    ┆ 14  ┆ 27  ┆ 3   │
│ C     ┆ 32  ┆ 32  ┆ 3   │
│ C+    ┆ 33  ┆ 38  ┆ 4   │
│ B-    ┆ 42  ┆ 45  ┆ 3   │
│ B     ┆ 45  ┆ 55  ┆ 3   │
│ B+    ┆ 55  ┆ 69  ┆ 4   │
│ A-    ┆ 72  ┆ 78  ┆ 3   │
│ A     ┆ 85  ┆ 88  ┆ 3   │
│ A+    ┆ 89  ┆ 100 ┆ 4   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

you can see that the boundaries between grades look good for A+, A, and A- but when you get to B+ its min is also the max of B so you'll two people with a 55 that got different letter grades. The same thing happens again between B and B- with the 45 score. Now, in some cases, you may be able to switch which groups have 3 or 4 people to make it work but there's no guarantee that would always work.

You can take the `'ordinal'` out of the rank, and in this case you get:

```
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ grade ┆ min ┆ max ┆ n   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ D     ┆ 0   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   │
│ C-    ┆ 14  ┆ 27  ┆ 3   │
│ C     ┆ 32  ┆ 32  ┆ 3   │
│ C+    ┆ 33  ┆ 38  ┆ 4   │
│ B-    ┆ 42  ┆ 45  ┆ 4   │
│ B     ┆ 55  ┆ 55  ┆ 3   │
│ B+    ┆ 66  ┆ 69  ┆ 3   │
│ A-    ┆ 72  ┆ 78  ┆ 3   │
│ A     ┆ 85  ┆ 88  ┆ 3   │
│ A+    ┆ 89  ┆ 100 ┆ 4   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

which is the fit you're looking for with this data. Although there's no guarantee that this works. This one risks having imbalanced groups.

Another approach is to assign the grades based on the unique test scores like this:

```
(df
    .select(
            test=pl.col('test').unique(),
            rank=(pl.col('test').unique().rank('ordinal').alias('rank')/(pl.col('test').unique().count()/10)).ceil().cast(pl.Int8())
)
    .with_columns(
        grade=pl.col('rank').map_dict({10:'A+',9:'A',8:'A-',7:'B+',6:'B',5:'B-',4:'C+',3:'C',2:'C-',1:'D'})
        )
)
```

and then join that to the original df like this:

```
(df
    .join(df
        .select(
                test=pl.col('test').unique(),
                rank=(pl.col('test').unique().rank('ordinal').alias('rank')/(pl.col('test').unique().count()/10)).ceil().cast(pl.Int8())
                )
        .with_columns(
            grade=pl.col('rank').map_dict({10:'A+',9:'A',8:'A-',7:'B+',6:'B',5:'B-',4:'C+',3:'C',2:'C-',1:'D'})
            ),
        on='test'
    )
)
```

in this case when you group by grade and aggregate by min/max/n we get this:

```
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ grade ┆ min ┆ max ┆ n   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ D     ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ C-    ┆ 10  ┆ 23  ┆ 3   │
│ C     ┆ 27  ┆ 32  ┆ 4   │
│ C+    ┆ 33  ┆ 37  ┆ 3   │
│ B-    ┆ 38  ┆ 43  ┆ 3   │
│ B     ┆ 45  ┆ 55  ┆ 5   │
│ B+    ┆ 66  ┆ 72  ┆ 4   │
│ A-    ┆ 77  ┆ 78  ┆ 2   │
│ A     ┆ 85  ┆ 88  ┆ 3   │
│ A+    ┆ 89  ┆ 100 ┆ 4   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

In this case, the groups are very imbalanced but since the grades are determined by unique test scores, there will never be a case where the same raw test score gives 2 different grades.